# Issues with Hovering Button

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to create a button that hovers over the content of my web page. 
How am I able to create this function?

This is the button I'm working with

```css
.button {
    background-color: red;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 15px 32px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<div class="button">Back</div>
```

Comment: So the button floats above the page content.

Comment: Please note that [Google is cracking down on interstitials](http://searchengineland.com/interstitialgeddon-google-warns-will-crack-intrusive-interstitials-next-january-257252) in the near future. I don't know if what you are making would qualify, but it might be worth your time to read into.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a full width overlay that will cover your entire page, and make your button center align inside it.

```css
.btn-holder {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 10;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
.button {
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background-color: red;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor site amet Lorem ipsum dolor site amet Lorem ipsum dolor site amet Lorem ipsum dolor site amet Lorem ipsum dolor site amet Lorem ipsum dolor site amet Lorem ipsum dolor site amet Lorem ipsum dolor site amet Lorem ipsum dolor site amet</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor site amet Lorem ipsum dolor site amet Lorem ipsum dolor site amet Lorem ipsum dolor site amet Lorem ipsum dolor site amet Lorem ipsum dolor site amet Lorem ipsum dolor site amet Lorem ipsum dolor site amet Lorem ipsum dolor site amet</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor site amet Lorem ipsum dolor site amet Lorem ipsum dolor site amet Lorem ipsum dolor site amet Lorem ipsum dolor site amet Lorem ipsum dolor site amet Lorem ipsum dolor site amet Lorem ipsum dolor site amet Lorem ipsum dolor site amet</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor site amet Lorem ipsum dolor site amet Lorem ipsum dolor site amet Lorem ipsum dolor site amet Lorem ipsum dolor site amet Lorem ipsum dolor site amet Lorem ipsum dolor site amet Lorem ipsum dolor site amet Lorem ipsum dolor site amet</p>
<div class="btn-holder">
  <div class="button">Back</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you this is what I needed.

Comment: @troxie Welcome to StackOverflow! If this answers your question, please don't forget to mark it correct!

Answer (score 0):

You can use button that hovers over the content

```
.button:hover {
    background-color: green;
}
```

and hover on content

```
.btn-holder:hover .button {
    background-color: green;
}
```